# Как правильно запросить глобальные данные после авторизации пользователя?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Ситуация такая: на сайте необходимо реализовать запрос некоторых общих данных для пользователя после авторизации, затем эти данные поместить в глобальный стор, так как они используются в остальных компонентах.

На данный момент я смог это реализовать таким образом.

Роутинг:

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
    <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
</Route>
<Route element={<MainLayout />}>
    ...
</Route>
```

MainLayout.jsx

```
const MainLayout = () => {
    const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector(userSelect);

    if (!isLoggedIn) return <Navigate to={'login'} replace />;

    return <ComponentWithFetchGlobalData />;
};

const ComponentWithFetchGlobalData = () => {  
    //fetch data...

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setData(data))
    }, [dispatch])

    return <Outlet />
}
```

Дополнительную обертку сделал на случай если неавторизованный пользователь попробует зайти на закрытый роут

Такая реализация решила проблему, но есть ощущение, что решение такое себе

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно более правильно решить данную задачу